# can I reuse the socket when update SSL certificate?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ssl, tcp

The old SSL certificate has expired and I want to renew the SSL certificate. However, the server already has established multiple links with other clients. So, can I just bind the old sockets to the new ssl, which means I don't need to disconnect the old base tcp links?

Comment: is "tls soft reset" what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existing TLS connections don't need to get updated with a new certificate - the server certificate is only checked at the beginning of the TLS connection. If your specific server supports updating the server certificate without a restart and thus without closing established connections is unknown - some do and some don't.

Comment: I forgot the server certificate is only checked at the beginning of the TLS connection. Thanks a lot.